What is the role of determinism in stochastics?
What is the role of determinism in stochastics?
In my opinion, determinism, much like the continuum, is merely a concept to describe an ideal world. In this idealized world we can calculate and argue. Whether, for example, the unit square and thus the length of its diagonal (= $\sqrt{2}$) exists in the “real” world or only in our imagination is, in my view, difficult to judge. However, it is very useful to complement rational numbers with irrational numbers and to calculate with them.
I see the role of determinism similarly. The random phenomena that may interest us and that we study are random precisely because we do not know the infinitely many influences and initial conditions, and we could not process them. This is determinism for me. And I even believe that this determinism is implicitly contained in the definition of a random variable. A random variable (= measurable function) assigns each element of a probability space exactly one element of a measurable space (= the interesting realizations of the phenomenon). Of course, we do not know this assignment; we only study the distribution of the assignment.
Is my perspective naive, or can anyone recommend literature that discusses this topic? Fundamentally, I am not seeking a philosophical evaluation or answer to determinism. Rather, I am interested in an argument that clarifies that our goal is not to answer the big questions of physics or philosophy, but to understand mathematics as a tool.

It is confusing what your question exactly is and what you mean by determinism (the idea that all events, including human will and events perceived as random, are intrinsicly predetermined), let alone it's 'role'. It sounds a bit vague and open to interpretation, similar to a question like say 'what is the role of god in mathematics?'.

There is some use of the term 'deterministic' here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=deterministic often it relates to a model or a part of a model that is without random influences. But that is different from the philosophical aspect.

Do all observations arise from probability distributions?

I have an approach to bridging determinism and probability theory that involves a substantial treatment in terms of order theory, topology and measure theory. But I don't see how this topic is anything other than (mathematically-refined) philosophy.

Is anything inherently random?

In fact, the question is a bit confusing, sorry for that! I have no idea how to make the question more precise. Let me put it this way: Is determinism allowed to be used as a mathematical concept irrespective of other disciplines like (quantum) physics or philosophy?

Mathematical concepts require some sort of definition. What is it that you mean by determinism, and that you want to use as a mathematical concept?

According to my perspective, the definition of a random variable is my (crude) definition of determinism. Every random observation has an unknown cause in terms of an unknown element of an underlying unknown probability space.
